# With TSQL, how do I convert a highly precise value to numeric?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having a pretty common problem but my usual solution isn't working. I've got a highly precise value stored as a character in a staging table. When I push it to it's final destination, a column with data type numeric(38,38), it fails. I thought it was because of the negative sign, but when I get rid of it, I still have an issue. I've got the numeric column maxed out but I'm still getting the following error:
Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

Normally I just convert to float but that isn't working. Besides which, I want to retain the precision of the value and float appears to take that away.

What am I missing here?

```
DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(255) = '-1.000000000000000'
SELECT CAST(@Value AS numeric(38,38))

DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(255) = '-1.000000000000000'
SELECT CAST(CAST(@Value AS FLOAT) AS numeric(38,38))
```

CLARIFICATION:
numeric(38,38) are absurd parameters and were only used for testing and as an example for this question. The original column was set to numeric(16,15) which worked more than 99% of the time on a dataset of millions of records and thus didn't flag as an issue.

Comment: The issue would be that you can't have a precision/scale of 38, 38 with a number >= 1 or <= -1 (because you've specified a precision of 38 after the decimal point).

Comment: Have you read the documentation of what `numeric(38, 38)` means???  It mean total of 38 digits, with 38 digits after decimal.  How would you expect that to work?

Comment: as ZLK said, you're forgetting the definition.  Just to completely spell it out--- with (38,38) you can have  .00000000000000000000000000000000000001 ... you can't have 1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000 == (38,37)

Comment: Yes I've read the documentation but this is probably a case of me not understanding what I read. decimal[ (p[ ,s] )] where s is confined to 0 through p. What it sounds like you're saying that even though -1. 15 zeros is the value, -1. 38 zeros is what is actually getting stored. There is some other complexity in my problem but I now see the basic issue.

Comment: @BobWakefield The precision is the total number of digits, including both left and right of the decimal. Scale is how far to shift the decimal from the end. In other words, something like (10,2) means 10 total digits, 2 of which are to the right of the decimal. This leaves a maximum of 8 to the left.

Comment: @BobWakefield For even more fun, wait until you use simple operators or aggregates on it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

numeric(38,38) is a numeric value of 38 digits, 38 of which are after the decimal. Because of this, any number greater than 1 or less than -1 (has 1 or more digits to the left of the decimal) will overflow. You need to account for the maximum number of digits that may occur to both the left and the right of the decimal.

1.00001 would be numeric(6,5) with 6 digits, 5 of which are on the right of the decimal, 1 of which is on the left.

10.00001 would be numeric(7,5) with 7 digits, 5 of which are on the right of the decimal, 2 of which are on the left.

Comment: Yeah 38,38 was a bit much. That came at the end of hours of trying to figure out why these values wouldn't fit in. I had saner settings at one point. The REAL failing here was not understanding that if the datatype was numeric(6,5), that the 5 wasn't a suggestion. Like 5 isn't a maximum value. If a number comes in at 1.1, it's actually going to get stored at 1.10000.